# How to run drkspider.sh on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java, sh

I have downloaded DRKSpiderJava v0.83 but I cannot run the file "drkspider.sh" on Windows 10.

I tried with `cmd`, CYG, `bash` but don't know why cannot open it. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you downloaded it from https://www.drk.com.ar/spider.php then the solution is to run `drkspider.cmd` instead. You will also need to make sure you have installed the [Java Runtime](https://java.com/en/download/) for it to run.

The `cmd` version will be a Windows shell script, the `sh` version would be specific to Linux.

The `ReadMe.txt` in the archive clearly states:

```
For running DRKSpiderJava on Windows, Linux or Mac graphical
environment try first:

* Double click on drkspiderjava.jar

If that doesn't work:

Windows

* Double click on drkspider.cmd

Linux or Mac

1. Be sure drkspider.sh has execution permission
2. Double click on drkspider.sh
```

Comment: I tried, doesn't work this way :(

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What happens? What do you see? How are you running it? Do you have [java](https://java.com/en/download/) installed? What errors do you get? You're going to need to provide more information @RobRob, preferably by [editing your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1617846/edit).

Comment: WORKS, you were right, I had to install java. Thank you very much.